# Optimize sorting methods

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, optimization, collections

I have two methods for sorting.
Sorting by priority and deadline.

```
fun getTargetsByPriority() {
    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            targetList.clear()
            dataSnapshot.children
                .mapNotNull { it.getValue(Goal::class.java) }
                .sortedBy { it.priority }
                .toCollection(targetList)
            contract.updateViewContent()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
        }
    }
    targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
}

fun getTargetsByDeadline() {
    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            targetList.clear()
            dataSnapshot.children
                .mapNotNull { it.getValue(Goal::class.java) }
                .sortedBy { it.deadline }
                .toCollection(targetList)
            contract.updateViewContent()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
        }
    }
    targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
}
```

But they are very similar to each other. How it possible to optimize this code?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any, R : Comparable<R>> DataSnapshot.sortChildrenTo(
  targetList: MutableList<T>, 
  crossinline sortCriteria: (T) -> R?
) {
  children.mapNotNull { it.getValue(T::class.java) }
    .sortedBy(sortCriteria)
    .toCollection(targetList)
}
```

Which then lets you write:

```
targetList.clear()
dataSnapshot.sortChildrenTo(targetList, Goal::priority)
```

Comment: But why u didn't use inner class for example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sortedBy you can use **sortedWith** and pass the comparator as a parameter.
so merge both of your functions into one function and take the comparator as a parameter. for example below function expects a String Comparator.

```
fun getTargets(comparator: Comparator<String>) {
}
```

now you can invoke this function as following

```
getTargets(Comparator{ o1, o2 -> o1.compareTo(o2)})
```

now use this compartor in your sortedWith function call, where you sort your list.

your calls would look something like following.

```
getTargets(Comparator{ o1, o2 -> o1.priority.compareTo(o2.priority)}) // For priority based sorting
getTargets(Comparator{ o1, o2 -> o1.deadline.compareTo(o2.deadline)}) // For deadline based sorting
```